# Origin for a CDN

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, cdn

I have some basic questions regarding configuring the CDN. I am using Amazon CloudFront for that.

1) Let's suppose my website is **example.com**. In the origin of cloudfront, do I mention **example.com** as the origin or create a CNAME like **cdn.example.com** which points to the server and then enter **cdn.example.com** as the origin?

2) Once the configuration is done, do I redirect **example.com** to the cloudfront domain like **dxxxxxx.cloudfront.net**?

3) I will update all the links in my website to **http://dxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/xxx**. Now when I browse **example.com**, I will be redirected to cloudfront. But cloudfront is also using the **example.com** as the origin. Isn't it like cloudfront is trying to pull data from itself? Won't that create a dead loop?

I am not able to get my head around this. I will be really grateful if someone could help. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how it works.

1. Your website is at example.com where all the static files are hosted that you want to serve through Cloudfront. This example.com is called the Origin Server, Origin Host, or simply the Origin.
2. Cloudfront will create a Pull Zone for you that will look like http://dxxxxxx.cloudfront.net - Now you have to use this host instead of the original example.com for your static assets. All HTML files or dynamic files will still be loaded directly through example.com . Users will still enter example.com in their browser. Only the scripts, styles, images, fonts, icons and similar static files that are loaded by the browser behind the scenes are required to be changed to use the CDN host.
3. **Your CDN setup is complete at this point**. However, if someone looks at the source code of your page, they can see the cloudfront URLs being used to deliver static assets. This may look unprofessional. As a solution to hide 3rd party Host Name, and to use your own host name to get a branded feel, you can create a new subdomain cdn.example.com at your DNS provider and CNAME it to dxxxxxx.cloudfront.net
4. If you created a CNAME subdomain above, you now have to update all URLs of static files again, and change their URL to use cdn.example.com . Your website will still be loaded over example.com, but assets will now be delivered through cdn.example.com that will point to dxxxxxx.cloudfront.net
5. When dxxxxxx.cloudfront.net will receive request from browser for static files, it will forward that request to the specified origin server example.com where the files are actually placed. Origin will send the files to cloudfront, cloudfront will save the file for future use and will send a copy to the browser.

Step 3, and 4 are not part of the CDN integration process. Also, the subdomain cdn.example.com is not a requirement. You can use some other subdomain, or some other domain. For example, the following are valid:

```
cdn2.example.com
static-assets.example.com
static.assets.example.com
images.example.parent-company-website.com
```

Similarly, it is not a requirement to fetch assets from example.com only. You can specify my-other-website.net as origin, and cloudfront will happily fetch resources from there for your example.com site.

In your scenario, all of the following are not dependent on each other. You can change any or all of these and the process will not break providing you made necessary adjustments to the configuration and the code.

```
Your website:  example.com
CDN origin:    example.com (since currently assets are at this host)
Pull Zone:     http://dxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/
CNAME Host:    cdn.example.com
```

Hope this clears the picture.

Comment: Hello @Hamid-Sarfraz

Most of it is clear. Thank you.

I have one doubt still. The HTML and dynamic contents are served from the original example.com like you mentioned in point 2. The static content are served by the CDN host and I need to change the links to the static files to http://dxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/

So CDN contacts the origin for static files, origin redirects it to the CDN link for the static files. Isn't this a loop here?

Comment: No, there is no loop. A loop would be created only if you setup a redirection at the server to redirect all requests coming for https://example.com/static/styles.css to https://dxx.cloudfront.net/static/styles.css --- You do not need such redirection. All you have to do is to edit your HTML and change all the links pointing to https://example.com/static/styles.css to now point to https://dxx.cloudfront.net/static/styles.css

Comment: If all this DNS stuff is complicated for you, then I would recommend you to go with [PageCDN](https://pagecdn.com). Setting up PageCDN for your website does not involve a DNS change, and is very easy overall.

Comment: Hello @HamidSarfraz, thanks for the detailed answer. I have a small query: Can the CDN origin (example.com) and the CNAME host be the same i.e. (example.com). So I have one k8s setup and in one of the proxy of it, I have example.com as vhost where ui resources are hosted. Can I use the same example.com as origin server and the CNAME host ?